# How to monitor active broadcastReceivers of my app?

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, ddms

Is it possible to somehow see if a particular broadcastReceiver is registered and running?

I'm facing a problem with the emulator. My code works fine on an actual device but not on an emulator. I'm adding proximity alerts and I have a class that implements `broadcastReceiver`. I register the receiver, but nothing happens when I run it on the emulator (I'm passing in valid location coordinates which should get caught by the proximity broadcast receiver).

I'm thinking that the `broadcastReceiver` object might be getting garbage collected. Otherwise I can't explain it.

Any ideas why this is happening? How can I debug this?

Comment: You need to tell us how you are setting up the `BroadcastReceiver`. Is it registered in the manifest, or via `registerReceiver()`? If the latter, what component is doing that -- an activity, a service, or something else? And is the component still around when you try sending location coordinates? Also, what emulator are you running this on? Android 2.3's emulator does not work with locations sent from DDMS, for example.

Comment: @Michael Fair point...I register the receiver via registerReceiver() from within an activity that is alive and in the foreground when I'm sending the coordinates...The emulator I'm running this on is using Google API's 2.2... Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it...Just needed to tick wipe user data apparently....